# Create PostgreSQL function using python

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql

I am creating trying to create a function inside PostgreSQL from python. My connection to PostgreSQL database uses psycopg2 and connects successfully in other instances. Code:

```
pg_cursor.execute('CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION %s.fix_geometry(geometry)\
                  RETURNS SETOF geometry AS\
                $BODY$\
                        SELECT geom the_geom\
                        FROM \
                                (\
                                SELECT (st_dump(st_buffer(st_snaptogrid(st_makevalid(the_geom), 0.5), 0))).geom\
                                FROM (SELECT geom the_geom FROM st_dump(st_snaptogrid($1, 0.5))) a\
                                ) b\
                        WHERE geometrytype(geom) = \'POLYGON\' AND st_area(geom) >= 0.01;\
                $BODY$\
                  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE\
                  COST 100\
                  ROWS 1000;' %(schema)) #line 84
pg_connection.commit()
pg_cursor.execute('ALTER FUNCTION %s.fix_geometry(geometry) OWNER TO analysis' % (schema))
pg_connection.commit()
```

I get error:

line 84, in 
    ROWS 1000;' %(schema))
ProgrammingError: type geometry does not exist

When I run the code in pgAdmin it executes successfully. What am I missing?

I had originally put this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41602531/4641482 but have yet to have had a response, maybe wrong forum?

Python 2.7, PostgreSQL 9.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the error was just outside of the provided code snippet. Postgre has the geometry type inside of the public schema and when I defined the search path for this code, I only defined the schema in which I was working; public was not included. So....

```
pg_cursor.execute('set search_path =  %s, public' % (schema))
pg_connection.commit()
```